# Subview view scroll as UITableView scrolls

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to create a sticky header like funcitionlity like in google map. when i scroll the tableview from top to down. i want to uiivew to be pulled down. i don't want to use any library or any control. [Demo Project link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B62pT4Le2is4a1JoR0ZMYzRXME0/edit?usp=sharing)

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
    {
        float delta = 0.0f;
        if (_tableView.contentOffset.y < 0.0f)
        {
            // Scroll down
            delta = fabs(MIN(0.0f, _tableView.contentOffset.y));
        }
        [self updateFrame:delta];
    }
    - (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
    {
        _originalCenter = self.UpperView.center;
    }
    -(void)updateFrame:(float)deltaY{
        self.UpperView.center = CGPointMake(_originalCenter.x, _originalCenter.y+deltaY);
    }

    #pragma mark - tableview delegate

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return 8;
    }
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cellIdentifier%i",indexPath.row];
        UITableViewCell * cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }
        [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %i",indexPath.row+1]];
        return cell;

    }
```

and I have created tableview with story board and added as subview to custom UIView(UpperView).

Comment: why you are not using default header view in table? header view is sticky & when you pull down to tableview header view is also pull down..

Comment: @iphoneDev- i am trying to scroll down the uiivew in which the tableview is subview.

Comment: Then make the tableview a subview of an outer tableview cell

Comment: @IvanKonov- can u elaborate some more